# Java - send Documents through ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, document, objectoutputstream

Ok so, I'm trying to create a browser that connects to a server and when the user enters in a url the browser sends that url to the server. The server then opens the url in a JEditorPane then uses the getDocument() method attempts to send that document through a ObjectOutputStream back to the client. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure this one out, is it not possible to send a Document through an objectoutputstream or what am I doing wrong?

Here's the code that I'm using:

Method that sets page and gets the Document:

```
url = (String) input.readObject();

window.setPage(url);
doc = window.getDocument();

sendDoc(doc);
```

Method that sends the Document through objectoutputstream:

```
try {

    output.writeObject(doc); // no compiling errors...
    output.flush();

} catch (Exception e) { }
```

Error that I get:

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted;
java.io.NotSerializableException:
javax.swing.text.html.CSS$Value is not serializable as a value in an AttributeSet
```

`...`

```
at DawgsCodeBrowser.whileConnected(DawgsCodeBrowser.java:101)
at DawgsCodeBrowser.Run(DawgsCodeBrowser.java:71)
at StartBrowser.main(StartBrowser.java:8)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
javax.swing.text.html.CSS$Value is not serializable as a value in an AttributeSet
```

`...`

```
at DawgsCodeServer.sendDoc(DawgsCodeServer.java:154)
at DawgsCodeServer.whileConnected(DawgsCodeServer.java:100)
at DawgsCodeServer.Run(DawgsCodeServer.java:59)
at StartServer.main(StartServer.java:11)
```

sorry for long error message, I took out some of it so it wouldnt be as long...

Comment: The object that you're trying to write does implement the `serializable` interface. First line in the error message. What class is `doc`?

Answer (score 2):

Says so right here:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.text.html.CSS$Value is not serializable as a value in an AttributeSet
```

This internal CSS$Value class is killing you, and there's probably not a whole lot you can do about it.

Rather you need to question why sending the Document is better than sending the actual raw HTML in this case.

Comment: Why is it trying to serialize `CSS.Value` in the first place? Isn't it sufficient to serialize `CSS`? `CSS` is a `Serializable`.

Comment: Because the data structure is referring to a CSS$Value internally. The java serializer is just walking the objects, and it stumbled upon an instance of CSS$Value, which obviously is not serializable. Once found, it ruins the whole party.